# Is there somewhere I can find a list of available colors for fill/stroke in ggvis?

Tags: r

I'm making a bar chart with ggvis in RStudio and would like to know if there is a list of possible colors to fill with. Thanks!

Comment: Easy. Type `colors in R` in your favorite web search engine.

Comment: Also, type the following into the R console in `RStudio` and behold! `demo("colors")`

Comment: @ShawnMehan - `demo("colors")` comes with R, whether you use RStudio or not.

Comment: There are also many other options. For example you can create your own color palettes using `rgb`, `hcl`, `hsv`, `colorRamp`, and `RColorBrewer::brewer.pal`, to name a few color-related functions.